What is the impedance of this system?
This may be silly but I've been reading a paper in which they calculated the overall impedance \$Z_m\$ of the following system as
$$Z_m = \frac{Z_tG+Z_sG}{Z_tY_p+Z_sY_p+1}$$

For some context, this is to calculate the the measured impedance (\$Z_m\$) assuming an unideal system with gain error G, serial error \$Z_s\$ and parallel error \$Y_p\$.
I tried deriving this equation myself as follows:
$$Z_m = G * \frac{Y_p*(Z_s+Z_t)}{Y_p + (Z_s+Z_t)} = \frac{Y_p(Z_tG+Z_sG)}{Z_s+Z_t+Y_p} = \frac{Z_tG+Z_sG}{\frac{Zs}{Y_p}+\frac{Zt}{Y_p} + 1}$$
which is very similar to the expression in the paper but different. Would really appreciate it if someone could point out what I missed in the process cause this seems like such a simple problem.

Yp+Zs+.. is wrong, they have different units. It's the parallel combination there that you need to write out.

@Designalog Sorry could you elaborate on what you mean by writing out the parallel combination?

Y is an admittance and Z is an impedance. You are treating them both as impedances @squarepotato

@squarepotato as Andy aka said, you're adding admittance and impedances. Give it some thought.

Sorry this is my mechanical background showing - I didn't recognize Y as being admittance and assumed it to be another impedance. A follow up question: Why use admittance for the parallel error term and impedance for the series error term?

@squarepotato because admittances in parallel add together, just like impedances in series add together.

@square potato: Also, conductance and admittances are sometimes used to represent huge resistances or impedances (such as the leakage in insulated cable) to make the numbers more convenient to use.

Thank you guys! Does that mean essentially admittance is used to make the resulting formula look cleaner & maybe make more sense intuitively?

There are many ways to solve this, but I'll go for the most explicit one.
You recognized, correctly, that \$Z_t+Z_s\$ as they are 2 impedances in series. However, admittance \$Y_p\$ (or, you can also call it impedance \$\frac{1}{Y_p}\$) is in parallel with \$Z_t+Z_s\$.
To put it in terms of impedances, I'll simply calculate the parallel combination of \$Z_t+Z_s\$ and \$\frac{1}{Y_p}\$. Using the textbook formula, we can simply write (this is before the gain multiplication factor in your block diagram):
$$
Z_{eq}=\frac{\frac{1}{Y_p}\left(Z_t+Z_s\right)}{\frac{1}{Y_p}+Z_t+Z_s} = \frac{Z_t+Z_s}{1+Z_tY_p+Z_sY_p} 
$$
Then, multiplying by the gain factor \$G\$, we arrive at the final expression:
$$
Z_m=GZ_{eq}= G\frac{Z_t+Z_s}{1+Z_tY_p+Z_sY_p} 
$$
Alternatively, you could've transformed the impedance \$Z_t+Z_s\$ into an admittance: \$\frac{1}{Z_t+Z_s}\$. Note, however, that for parallel impedances, you have to apply that formula I wrote above. This doesn't apply to admittances, which, on the other hand, only a simple addition is needed (like a dual of the addition of series impedances):
$$
Y_{eq}=Y_p + \frac{1}{Z_t+Z_s} 
$$
This would be the equivalent measured admittance. You can simplify this expression and take the inverse to arrive at the \$Z_{eq}\$ as well.
